# Sheafification via compatible germs for Grothendieck topologies?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

I currently been reading a bit about Grothendieck topology in the book "Introduction to Etalé Cohomology" by Tamme. I've just gotten to the part where the author define the sheafification via the functor
$$
(\_)^+ : \mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{P} 
$$
which takes an abelian presheaf
$$
F : T \rightarrow \text{Ab}
$$
to a seperated presheaf which in turn is taken to a sheaf by applying the functor again. My question naively is what stops us from defining sheafification of (abelian) sheaves similarly as done e.g. with compatible germs (as in Vakil's notes)? Is there just more generality in this construction?

Thank you very much for any help :)

Comment: In general sites, there may not be enough points to make the maps $\mathcal{F}(U) \rightarrow \prod_{x \in U}{\mathcal{F}_x}$ injective (with set-theoretical notation of course, to be adapted – especially in this case as there can be several ways a point factors through an “étale open subset”), as is done in the “merely” topological case. Of course, on the étale site there *are* enough such points.

Comment: Even when there are enough points it is not obvious how to make the set of points into a topological space, and even once that is done it is not obvious how to get from a sheaf on that topological space back to a sheaf on the original site, nor that the sheaf you get has the required universal property.

Comment: @ZhenLin It is possible to "avoid" this by defining the sheaf as the compatible germs (how ever one would do that) for F(U) as Vakil does (not constructing the étalé topological space)? Then we atleast maybe avoid the dilemma of associating the topological space to the site?

Comment: You will find that the Grothendieck plus construction is in fact the construction of the set of compatible sections, skipping the translation into germs.